# How to show white text on an image with black border using OpenCV2?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following line of code to put text on an image but it is not legible on most occasions. How can I make the text white but with a black border around the text?

```
cv2.putText(img=image_in, text=traffic_light_state, org=(center[0] + 50, center[1]),
            fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , fontScale=1, color=[255, 255, 255], lineType=cv2.CV_AA, thickness=2)
```

Comment: Draw your text (in white) on a separate empty image, create a copy of that image and use `dilate` function on it. You get a thicker image of your text. Put the dilated text image, inverting its color (so it turns black), on top of your original image, then put the white text you drawn first on top of that.

Answer (score 27):

The way I do it in my code is by drawing the same text twice. Once in the outline color with double thickness (adjust to your liking), and once in the text color afterwards.

```
cv2.putText(img=image_in, text=traffic_light_state, org=(center[0] + 50, center[1]),
        fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , fontScale=1, color=[0, 0, 0], lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, thickness=4)
cv2.putText(img=image_in, text=traffic_light_state, org=(center[0] + 50, center[1]),
        fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , fontScale=1, color=[255, 255, 255], lineType=cv2.LINE_AA, thickness=2)
```

In my experience, dilate, as recommended in comments, isn't the fastest. And addWeighted can be expensive if used in images as large as I frequently edit. There definitely are tricks to fix the speed in both instances, but this method is just easier.

```
size = cv2.getTextSize("Test", cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, 4)[0]
im = np.ones((size[1], size[0]), np.uint8)*127
cv2.putText(im, "Test", (0,size[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (0,), 4)
cv2.putText(im, "Test", (0,size[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (255,), 2)
cv2.imwrite("test.png", im)
```

yields [image: this image.] (Not entirely sure about the cut-off, but that's usually not an issue when inserting into an already made image.)

Comment: cv2.CV_AA is cv2.LINE_AA

Comment: the color with the higher thickness should be drawn first,
For this case the black.

It is done correctly in this code just wanted to added as a note since it took me 10 mnts to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just make the text sit on top of a transparent overlay as seen below:

```
overlay_image = np.copy(image_in)
cv2.rectangle(img=overlay_image, pt1=(center[0] + 50, center[1] - 50), pt2=(center[0] + 350, center[1] + 50),
              color=[0, 0, 0], thickness=-1)
cv2.putText(img=overlay_image, text=traffic_light_state, org=(center[0] + 50, center[1] + 10),
            fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, fontScale=1, color=[255, 255, 255], thickness=1)
cv2.addWeighted(src1=overlay_image, alpha=0.5, src2=image_in, beta=0.5, gamma=0, dst=image_in)
```